# How can I pass default values via a route in CakePHP without URL parameter involvement?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to pass in a value to my Controller (in this case PagesController) that does not come from the URL. I simply would like to do something *like* this:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'), array('foo' => 'bar'));
```

Then, in PagesController.php, I have:

```
public function display() {
    $path = func_get_args();
    error_log(var_export($path,TRUE));
    error_log(var_export($this->request->params,true));
}
```

Which I expect to have my passed parameter 'foo' with the value 'bar' somewhere.

I've tried a number of seemingly promising methods from: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

But none of them seem to do what I'm after.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is apparently:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'foo' => 'bar', 'home'));
```

It can be retrieved thusly:

```
error_log($this->request->params['layout']);
```